# Jquery: How to return all the data in my Jquery to html when the document is ready?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page in which it has to returns data from a JSON. I made a filter in such a way that it returns the values based on the filter. Here my problem is, the page is not displaying all values when the document is ready even I made the radio button "All" as checked by default. It works when I click on radio buttons later. Can someone help me how can I return all values when the page is initiated?

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sDsCM/805/

Html:

```
<fieldset class="question">
   <input class="hello" type="radio" name="filter" value="All" checked/>
   <span class="item-text">All</span>
   <input class="hello" type="radio" name="filter" value="1"/>
   <span class="item-text">One</span>
   <input class="hello" type="radio" name="filter" value="2" />
   <span class="item-text">Two</span>
   <input class="hello" type="radio" name="filter" value="3" />
   <span class="item-text">Three</span>
</fieldset>

<div id="dbg">

</div>
```

Javasript:

```
  var i;

  $("input[name=filter]").on('change', function () {
        var no = $(this).val();                
        i=no;
        var dmJSON="http://api.railwayapi.com/route/train/12728/apikey/3dacdecg/";

        $.getJSON( dmJSON, function(data) {
                var el = $('#dbg');
                var html = '<div class="row s12"/>';
                $.each(data.route, function(key, value) {                  
                     if(i=="All"){                  
                        html +='<div class="card small">' +'<div align="center">' + value.no + "<br><br>" + value.fullname + "</div>" + "</div>" +"</div>"
                     }
                     else if(value.no==i){
                        html +='<div class="card small">' +'<div align="center">' + value.no + "<br><br>" + value.fullname + "</div>" + "</div>" +"</div>"
                     }      
                });
                el.html(html);
        });
   });
```

Comment: 10/10 best formatted code I've ever seen

Comment: What I see is, you have bind only change event of radio buttons. You need to wrap the all content in a function, that function should be called on change event as well as first time when dom is loaded

Comment: _“even I made the radio button "All" as checked by default”_ – exactly, the default that is set already when the page loads - so naturally it does _not_ fire a change event, but your script is only triggered by that event. Simple solution: Trigger the event from within your script on page load, using http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API seems to be not working message is **"Quota exhausted for day"** but i have updated code as you can find in below snipeet you just have to add one function which is load data on page load as well as on change function

```js
var i;
  var el = $('#dbg');
     var HtmlData =  LoadData();
  el.html(HtmlData);
  $("input[name=filter]").on('change', function () {
 var no = $(this).val
 i=no;
 var HtmlData =  LoadData();
    el.html(HtmlData);
  });
        
    function LoadData()
    {
     var dmJSON="http://api.railwayapi.com/route/train/12728/apikey/3dacdecg/";
     var html = '<div class="row s12"/>';
  $.ajax({
    url: dmJSON,
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: {},
    success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.route, function(key, value) {  
    if(i=="All"){
     html +='<div class="card small">' +'<div align="center">' + value.no + "<br><br>" + value.fullname + "</div>" + "</div>" +"</div>"
       }
   else if(value.no==i){
      html +='<div class="card small">' +'<div align="center">' + value.no + "<br><br>" + value.fullname + "</div>" + "</div>" +"</div>"
      }
   });
                    
  }
    });
   return html;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="question">
       <input class="hello" type="radio" name="filter" value="All" checked/>
       <span class="item-text">All</span>
       <input class="hello" type="radio" name="filter" value="1"/>
       <span class="item-text">One</span>
       <input class="hello" type="radio" name="filter" value="2" />
       <span class="item-text">Two</span>
       <input class="hello" type="radio" name="filter" value="3" />
       <span class="item-text">Three</span>
   </fieldset>

   <div id="dbg">
      
   </div>
```

Comment: Its is working as before. Couldn't able to get "All" data when the page is initiated. Can you please help me.  How can i pass the LoadData() without any condition when the page is initiated

Comment: `var i ="All" ` replace first line by this and hopefully things gonna work as expected as i can't check because api is broken so try this if anything wrong let me know

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks, Dude. You are awesome.

Comment: Ohh that's great glad it helps you